# VSCode C++ debugger doesn't show content of vectors items

Tags: c++, vscode-debugger

I use VSCode with C++ extension on Mac Os, and I'm not able to see the content of anything vector in the debugger:

[image]

All those lists are always empty. Is that a bug or I am missing some esoteric setup?
Thank you

Comment: Are you using `std` vector or `boost`/`Qt`? If the last ones, you need to add `gdb pretty-printers`. Search for them.

Comment: I'm using plain std::vector, and frontend is llvm